# Prism Could not Found Services

Tags: prism

this is the first Step for Getting Start Prism Example [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/getting-started.html) says

using System.Windows;

using Prism.Ioc;

using Prism.Unity;

namespace WpfApp1

{

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.Register<Services.ICustomerStore, Services.DbCustomerStore>();
        // register other needed services here
    }

    protected override Window CreateShell()
    {
        var w = Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        return w;
    }
}
```

}

the problem is in this line *containerRegistry.Register<Services.ICustomerStore* where It coulnt Find Services also it suggest two but none of them has thefollowing ICustomerStore

Answer (score 1):

Services is supposed to be a project/namespace that you make in your solution, which acts as a layer to access your database.  ICustomerStore is an interface that you give to the DI container, and DbCustomerStore is the implementation that accesses the database.  So, for example, an incredibly simple version might look like:

ICustomer.cs:

```
public interface ICustomer {
    List<Customer> GetAllCustomers();
}
```

DbCustomer.cs:

```
public class DbCustomer : ICustomer
{
    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        AppDbContext dbContext = new();
        return dbContext.Customers.ToList();
    }
}
```

The point is to isolate the details of accessing the database in the DbCustomer class, so you can actually create a different version of it if you need to change the type of database you're using that would require different code, like writing an XmlCustomers class that also inherits from ICustomer, but uses an XML file for the database.

Comment: thanx. but as it shows on that page prismlibrary(the link is first Line of My question) it was a simple project and I just follow the page first Install the Nuget Packages next Override the Existing Application Object and I Also chacked all lines with my code to be sure its correct as i get to the part: RegisterTypes. i got error redLine under Service. still i Couldnt find a way to correct it.

Comment: You're supposed to write that part yourself.  Everything in the Service namespace is your data access code.  The name "Services" is totally arbitrary.